monotonicity of Dirichlet energy under different Dirichlet boundary conditions.
Let $\Omega$ be a domain with two smooth boundaries in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Suppose $u_1$ is a harmonic function in $\Omega$ satisfying that $u=0$ in $\partial_1\Omega$ and $u=1$ in $\partial_2\Omega$. There are two functions $f_1<0$ on $\partial_1\Omega$ and $f_2>1$ on $\partial_2\Omega $. Suppose $u_2$ is a harmonic function with boundary conditions $f_1$ and $f_2$. Can we compare their Dirichlet energy? i.e., is the following true?
$$\int_\Omega |\nabla u_1|^2\leq \int_\Omega|\nabla u_2|^2$$
